# Web3j client not exit after unsubscribe

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, java

I use web3j to fetch information from ethereum blockchain,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Web3j web = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://10.9.59.138:18001"));
    Observable<EthBlock> observable = web.blockObservable(true);
    Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    System.out.println("main say good bye.");
    // jvm not exit!
}
```

As mentioned in the official document, subscriptions should always be cancelled when no longer required. So I call unsubscribe(), but the JVM not exit.
How can I quit properly?

Answer (score 1):

Although your code worked for me, you can ensure a proper exit by calling:

```
System.exit(0);
```